# Attach jquery onclick event to element in iframe where element is not yet rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have iframe on my web page. Iframe contains a wizard type form and I need to know when the user finished the wizard in order to continue with the main page. The last step of the wizard will contain the submit button.

How I can attach to that button on the main page? At the moment of rendering iframe buttons are not visible.

I have tried following with no luck:

```
$('#iframe_id').on('click','#submit_wizard', function(){
        alert('wizard form submitted, time to continue');
    })
```

Comment: Is the content of the iframe on the same domain as the parent page? If it is, then you need to use a delegated parent element which is *inside* that frame, not the frame itself. If not, then what you're attempting to do is not possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's on a different domain. Is there any other way to monitor contents of iframe?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not, for a variety of security reasons.

Comment: Understood, would subdomain work? Example: 

main page: www.test.com
iframe: www.wizard.test.com

Comment: No, the domains need to be identical, down to the port used.